# Seleium and Geckodriver not working python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am trying to write a program using selenium in python that will open a firefox window and go to twitter. I have placed the geckdriver.exe in my python 3.6 folder and installed firefox. I have also ran 'pip install selnium' and installed selenium.

This is the code i have written:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Harry\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\geckodriver.exe")
browser.get("https://www.twitter.com/")`
```

When run the output is:

> PS C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\Coding\Python\Bots\TwitterBot> python app.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "app.py", line 5, in 
>       browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>     File "C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 174, in **init**
>       keep_alive=True)
>     File "C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in **init**
>       self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
>     File "C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
>     File "C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Why is this and what can i do to fix it? 
I am using python 3.6 and Visual Studio Code to code my program. 
Firefox version is latest one out at time of writing.

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1178 This github issue might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try one of these solutions:

- Use DesiredCapabilities:

  ```
  from Selenium import webdriver

  from Selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

  cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX

  cap["marionette"] = False

  browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap, executable_path="C:\\Users\\Harry\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\geckodriver.exe")

  browser.get('https://twitter.com/')

  browser.quit()
  ```
- Updating Firefox and Selenium and  reinstall geckodriver